# How to use java classpath in windows command line?

Tags: java

I have created a java source file in **Source** folder and also created a folder named **classes** which is supposed to contain my class files .

```
javac -d classes Source/TestMyAnnotation.java
```

puts my files in the directory structure **classes/Source/...**

Now I want to run that compiled classes but

```
java -cp classes/Sources TestMyAnnotation
```

throwing **NoClassDefFoundError**
Where am I doing wrong? How to do it in a correct way?

Comment: You probably need to define the `--sourcepath` for your compiler. Read the [javac documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#basic).

Comment: have you tried with absolute path of class file. java -cp absolutepathofclassfile

Answer (score 0):

Sources is not a package folder; it's just the directory that holds your java source, so you don't need to put it on your classpath. If you take a look inside your `classes` directory after you have compiled your java source, you will see a file `TestMyAnnotation.class` - there's no `Sources` directory underneath it, so you don't specify it on the classpath.

You will be able to run your class like this:

```
java -cp classes TestMyAnnotation
```

You can find more information on how all this works on Oracle's [Managing Source and Class Files Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)